# Jumping in pygame + understanding pygame math (vector)

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

sprites.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
vec = pg.math.Vector2
# for movement

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 153))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
def jump(self):
    self.rect.x += 1
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
    self.rect.x -= 1
    if hits:
        self.vel.y = -20

def update(self):
    self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
    # pouze zryhlení
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = - PLAYER_ACC
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

    # apply friction
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
    # pohyb tělesa
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
        self.pos.x = 0
    if self.pos.x < 0:
        self.pos.x = WIDTH

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

main.py:

```
import random
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from sprites import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the game window
        self.running = True
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption('My game')
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def new(self):
        # to start a new game, reset the pieces
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        p1 = Platform(0, HEIGHT - 40, WIDTH, 40)
        p2 = Platform(WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT * 3 / 4, 100, 20)
        self.platforms.add(p2)
        self.platforms.add(p1)
        self.all_sprites.add(p1)
        self.all_sprites.add(p2)
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
        if hits:
            self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            self.player.rect.midbottom = self.player.pos
            self.player.vel.y = 0

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass


game = Game()
game.show_start_screen()

while game.running:
    game.new()
    game.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

settings.py:

```
# game settings
WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# player settings
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = ((255, 255, 153))
```

I have a few questions:

Question n. 1:

Why doesn't the jump method work? And why is it using velocity -20 to jump?

Question n. 2:
I'm not quite sure if I understand the vector coordinates, can someone please try to explain it to me?
I think that this is exactly why I have problems understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame, the screen coordinates start at the top left (0,0). Positive Y goes down. Jump is -20 because the player is going up (toward zero). It looks like the player bounces up when it hits an object.

[image: Pygame Screen]

Concerning the jump issue, the game does not start for (Platform not defined) so I can't help there.